# windowResize problem

Tags: javascript, window-resize

I want to make a web browser adjustment margin left. I use windowResize, but how to adjustment margin left even if the custom click the restore button of the web browser? I upload 2 screenshort images for explain. [image]first image, I open the web browser not maximize, so the page make a windowResize and count the margin-left, then I click the windows maximize, then get the [image]second image, but the content is not in the center of the page. How to do a right windowResize? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
       var width = document.body.clientWidth;   
       windowResize(width);   
       $(window).resize(function() {      
           windowResize(width);      
           }); 
       });  
    function windowResize(width) {   
    if(width>1024){      
    $('#content').css({        
       'margin-left':(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px'      
       });  
    }else{
        $('#content').css({        
       'margin-left': 32 + 'px'      
       });
    }
    } 
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>  
    body, #box{min-width:1024px;width:100%;}  
    #content{float:left;width:960px;height:300px;background-color:#F00;}   
    </style>  
    <div id="box">  
    <div id="content">
        some words
    </div>  
    </div>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question languished, I think it was asked quite well. Nice example of a code reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that this code will only ever call `windowResize` with the initial width:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   // this value will always be passed to windowResize
   var width = document.body.clientWidth;   
   windowResize(width);   
   $(window).resize(function() {      
       windowResize(width);      
       }); 
   });
```

I changed it so the width is calculated inside of `windowResize` and things work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  windowResize();   
  $(window).resize(windowResize); 
});  

function windowResize() {
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;   
  if(width>1024){      
    $('#content').css({        
       'margin-left':(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px'      
    });
  }else{
    $('#content').css({        
       'margin-left': 32 + 'px'      
    });
  }
}
```

​